# $S$-matrix in QED in 2d space-time

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, physics

I am not completely sure that this question is appropriate for this site, but I have asked a similar question here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/271372/s-matrix-in-qed-in-2d-space-time and did not get an answer. Also on this site I got in the past some nice answers to questions related to physics.

I am interested in the S-matrix in QED in 2-dimensional Minkowski space-time.

1) Do I understand correctly that In and Out states of physical interest in the 2d case include fermions only (because photons have no physical polarizations)?

2) Is it possible to compute the S-matrix  perturbatively like in the classical 4d case? If yes, what is the propagator of the free EM field?

Comment: if I am not mistaken in 2D QED (Schwinger model) there are only confined fermions; how might we then even define a scattering matrix, when there are no asymptotically free states at infinity?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: I am not well familiar with the Schwinger model, but my impression was that in this model fermions are massless. I did not assume that in my question. I believe this assumption may lead to some extra divergences in the S-matrix.

Comment: for the scattering matrix in the massive Schwinger model see this [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9701013)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Thanks for the relevant reference. It is not self contained, so it may take me some time to figure out whether it contains answers to my questions.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the book [Non-Perturbative Methods in 2 Dimensional Quantum Field Theory](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/4678) by Abdalla, Abdalla and Rothe. That should be selfcontained and certainly discusses exact S-matrices and 2d QED, so the answer to your questions might be in there.